# SAML 2.0 and C# Request to Service Provider .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml

I am working on a project that requires a single sign on. System A looks up the username and password in the database and System B only authenticates with SAML 2.0. In this instance System B will be the Service Provider (SP). I am relatively new to SAML SSO so I am not 100% sure my approach is correct. System A would have to be the IDP I am guessing. A user would sign into System A and upon a successful login further information is posted to System B to complete the SSO process. Would this be accurate?

Answer (score 2):

Your description is correct. System A is the IdP as this is where the user is authenticated and from where a SAML assertion is issued. System B is the SP and it will perform an automatic local login of the user using information contained in the SAML assertion.

If the user starts at the IdP site, logs in, and clicks a link to SSO to the SP site, this is referred to as IdP-initiated SSO. If they start at the SP site, this is referred to as SP-initiated SSO. Your scenario sounds like IdP-initiated SSO.

The IdP will send a SAML response containing a SAML assertion to the SP using an HTTP/Post.